# Implement interface in Fragment

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement an interface on a fragment. For this I created a Class "X" to perform an action. In this class I created a method that uses the interface object and in the fragment, I implement the interface and create an object of class "X", which calls the method that uses the interface object. As you can see in the code below.

The

```
public class ClassX {

private NewInterface newInterface;

public void sum(){

    newInterface.sum(1,1);

}

}
```

The interface

```
public interface NewInterface {

    public void sum(int a,int b);
}
```

The fragment

```
public class ExampeleFragment extends Fragment implements NewInterface {

    private ClassX classx;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_example, container, false);

        classx.sum(1,1);

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void sum(int a, int b) {
        
        int sum = a+b;

    }
}
```

And I'm getting the error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference

The NewInterface object in class x is null. However, this procedure works when I implement it in the MainActivity class. Does anyone know what may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the NullPointerException because you did not assign anything to the **newInterface** property in your ClassX object.

I don't understand why you call `classx.sum(1,1);` while your **sum** method on ClassX doesn't accept any parameters.

Try this:
Create a constructor for your ClassX which takes a **NewInterface** parameter. So your ClassX would look like this:

```
public class ClassX {

private NewInterface newInterface;

public ClassX(NewInterface newInterface) {
    this.newInterface = newInterface;
}

public void sum(){

    newInterface.sum(1,1);

}

}
```

and then initialize your classX object like this:

```
classX = new ClassX(this);
```

before calling

```
classX.sum();
```

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten to put the parameters in this example. I passed the interface on the class x constructor and it worked.